# MSSQL: Select 1 record of each result with same value (similiar to FirstOrDefault)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of records with duplicate phone numbers.  We need to arbitrarily assign 1 record to be the master, so what I'm trying to do is write an MS SQL script to grab the first instance of each active Phone number and ignore the rest.  Similar to how FirstOrDefault works in C# Linq.

Example Data

```
Steve | 555-1234 | Active
Mike  | 555-1234 | Active
Bryan | 555-1234 | Inactive
Jane  | 555-5678 | Active
Tara  | 555-5678 | Inactive
Pete  | 555-5678 | Active
```

So I want my results to show 1 entry of 555-1234 and 1 of 555-5678 but only of my active records.  I don't care which of the active names I get as I'm arbitrarily assigning one as a master.

Comment: In order to use ROW_NUMBER properly you need to give us an order by for what column you want.  If you don't care pick a column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE MyPeeps (
     Name VARCHAR(10),
     Phone VARCHAR (10),
     Status VARCHAR( 10)
);

INSERT INTO MyPeeps (Name, Phone, Status) VALUES ('Steve','555-1234','Active');
INSERT INTO MyPeeps (Name, Phone, Status) VALUES ('Mike','555-1234','Active');
INSERT INTO MyPeeps (Name, Phone, Status) VALUES ('Bryan','555-1234','Inactive');
INSERT INTO MyPeeps (Name, Phone, Status) VALUES ('Jane','555-5678','Active');
INSERT INTO MyPeeps (Name, Phone, Status) VALUES ('Tara','555-5678','Inactive');
INSERT INTO MyPeeps (Name, Phone, Status) VALUES ('Pete','555-5678','Active');
```

This works:

```
SELECT PHONE 
FROM MyPeeps 
WHERE Status = 'Active'
GROUP BY PHONE;
```

See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/086e79/2

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **ROW_NUMBER**

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Phone 
              ORDER BY ColumnNameYouWantOrderBy) RN
    FROM Table_Name
    WHERE Status = 'Active'
) RS
WHERE RS.RN = 1
```